# Automatically update particular data of a specific column with new data in all tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
--TO UPDATE PARTICULAR COLUMN IN ALL TABLES IN A DATABASE
declare 
      @query nvarchar(max)='',
      @newValue varchar(10)='NEWVALUEHERE', 
      @oldValue varchar(10)='OLDVALUEHERE'

select 
    @query = @query + ' Update ' +
             quotename(object_name(c.object_id)) + 
             ' set [COLUMNNAMEHERE] = @newValue where [COLUMNNAMEHERE] = @oldValue ;'
from 
    sys.columns c 
join
    sys.all_objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id 
where 
    c.name = 'COLUMNNAMEHERE' and o.type = 'U'

select @query

--IF EVERYTHING SEEMS FINE COMMENT THE UPPER LINE AND UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW AND EXECUTE
--exec sp_executesql @query, N'@newValue varchar(10), @oldValue varchar(10)', @newValue=@newValue,@oldValue=@oldValue
```

So, I have this query that gets the job done, but  after executing `select @query` I need to manually copy paste the result and replace the `;` with `\n go \n` in `' Update ' + quotename(object_name(c.object_id)) + ' set [COLUMNNAMEHERE] = @newValue where [COLUMNNAMEHERE] = @oldValue ;'`  using regular expression option in <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd> due to potential errors that could end the query execution prematurely.

Due to which the last line of my query

```
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@newValue varchar(10), @oldValue varchar(10)', @newValue=@newValue,@oldValue=@oldValue
```

is rendered useless and I am unable to make this query automatic.

Comment: Why do you need to add a carriage return? This looks like it would run just fine. You have a semicolon to terminate each statement.

Comment: No, the semicolon doesn't get the job done and query execution is stopped after first error due to which I need to add GO to the query. But being the result of execution in single row I need to add a carriage return for the query to work with GO.

Comment: On the contrary, the semicolon will terminate the statement. But you didn't mention anything previously about errors. An error will cause your sp_executesql to fail. It isn't going to run the statements in that batch one by one. And the GO is ONLY in SSMS to indicate a batch terminator. It seems you are wanting to run all of your statements each in their own batch.

Comment: This screams of being an https://xyproblem.info/ problem.

Comment: Sorry if my way of portraying it wasn't clear . Sincerest apologies. But I did mention about error stating that I had to replace the semicolon with \n GO \n due to potential errors that could end the query execution prematurely

Comment: My apologies, I missed the part about the errors. But using the GO keyword won't help as I mentioned. Sounds like a different approach to the original problem you were trying to solve may be in order.

Comment: I'd suggest you try work out why errors are happening and prevent them from happening in the first place. Also `select @query = @query +` is not the correct way to aggregate, you should use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, just use `CHAR(10)` in your dynamic SQL:

```
declare 
      @query nvarchar(max)='',
      @newValue varchar(10)='NEWVALUEHERE', 
      @oldValue varchar(10)='OLDVALUEHERE'

select @query = @query + 'Update ' + quotename(object_name(c.object_id)) + ' set [COLUMNNAMEHERE] = @newValue where [COLUMNNAMEHERE] = @oldValue;' + CHAR(10) + 'GO' + CHAR(10)
from sys.columns c JOIN sys.all_objects o on c.object_id=o.object_id 
where c.name = 'COLUMNNAMEHERE' and o.type='U'

select @query
```

Comment: char(10) and char(13) were options but it will only provide required results in Ctrl+T execution and I don't think I can execute my "exec sp_executesql @query" in text mode so I guess it won't be enough to make the query fully automatic? Please correct me if I'm wrong and guide me on how I could make it full automatic !! Thanks.